# Express is res.sending both success and error - ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT

Tags: node.js, express

I have strange problem with `[ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: : Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`. It's in `try/catch`, but still somehow after `res.send({message: 'Company set up'})` it also sends `res.send({error})` which shouldn't occur.

I also tried `return res.send({message: 'Company set up'})`, but I have still same error. Along with that error I also get:

`(node:19234) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)`.

What I found that there is no problem when `await knex()` calls are commented out.

```
try {
      if (req.files) { //multer
        let data = req.body
        const locations = JSON.parse(data.locations)

        const parsedLocations = locations.map((obj, index) => {
          (...)
        })

        await asyncForEach(parsedLocations, async (element, index) => {
          const country = await knex('countries').first().where({ country: element.country })
        })

        console.log('company set up')
        res.send({ message: 'Company set up' })
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error')
      console.log(error)
      res.send({ error})
    }
```

Here's the `asyncForEach` function for reference:

```
async function asyncForEach(array, callback) {
  for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    await callback(array[index], index, array);
  }
}
```

Error log from Node.js:

```
[ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:470:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/Users/xx/Developer/microservice/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:767:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/Users/xx/Developer/microservice/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:170:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (/Users/xx/Developer/microservice/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:267:15)
    at ServerResponse.send (/Users/xx/Developer/microservice/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:158:21)
    at router.post (/Users/xx/Developer/microservice/routes/admin.js:714:11)
(node:19337) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 3)
```

Comment: can you give error log on node.js side?

Comment: @SagarRanaMagar updated my question with error log

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to trying to send multiple response.

You can check if response has been already sent or not before returning response.
Like:

```
if (res.headerSent) {
res.send({ data/ error})
```

If already sent, then it will not send another.

Your code is not catching the error.

Comment: It's just interesting why most of the time it works and sometimes it doesn't. I added even screenshot of network requests for reference. Will try that.

Comment: give screenshot of error log, I will try to debug it.

Comment: Use try/catch inside the asyncForEach function also.

Comment: Would you elaborate more why try/catch around the whole thing is not enough? I'd rather understand what I'm doing so I can use it in future as well

Comment: Ok, it doesn't work - I even checked if that async loop spits everything out before next function and it does so try/catch didn't helped

Comment: have use if(res.headersSent) things.

Comment: I will get back to you with solution . @SagarRanaMagar

Comment: The problem is that `res.send()` is sent but it doesn't stop function from calling `res.send()` from `catch` block as well

Comment: I found out that when commented out `await knex()` calls there are no problems so there must be issue with `async/await`. Still looking for solution because I need these calls.

Comment: Can you use await knex().catch(err=> console.log(err))

Answer (score 0):

```js
return res.status(405).send('User already exist');
```

Comment: I'm not creating any user. The only `insert` is conditional which hits only when country does not exists.

Comment: this example showing response than return keyword use so not geeting ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT errors